# In calabash-android After disale the data/Wifi , I am not able to access the app Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "1

Tags: calabash-android

In calabash-android After disale the data/Wifi , I am not able to access the app

irb(main):003:0> %x(adb shell svc wifi disable)
""
irb(main):004:0> %x(adb shell svc data disable)
""
irb(main):005:0> query("*")
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 34777 (127.0.0.1:34777)

Answer (score 1):

`adb` Can be used over Wi-Fi or over usb :

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

If you're using it over wi-fi, and disable the connection it will disconnect.

If adb over Wi-Fi is not your case, then we need more info.